# store array from php into a html input element

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I need to store an array from php into a HTML input hidden field.

PHP Controller :

```
    $docNames = array();
    if(!empty($records))
    {
        foreach($records as $item)
        {
            array_push($docNames, $item['description']);
        }
    }
    $this->f3->set('docNames', $docNames);
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="docNames[]" value="<?php echo $docNames; ?>">
</form>
```

But I am not being able to do so.
How can I store the array?

Comment: Do `print_r($docNames)`. What's the output?

Comment: @HtmHell yeah.. worked..thanks.. :)

Comment: you could also use `implode(",", $docNames);` if you wanted a comma separated string, then you could convert back into an array in another script using `explode(",",$docNames)`

Comment: Please don't use implode/explode like this! It will break when you least expect it.

Answer (score 2):

As Erwin says, using serialize offers a lot of benefits for managing the data. However it also has some security risks if you cannot trust the provenance of the data.

Given that you want to inject it into a hidden field, you presumably don't want the user to edit it. But you have no implicit means to prevent the user from changing the data. Using htmlentities() to escape the data creates some complications. It sounds like you need something like:

```
 define("MY_SECRET", sesion_id());

 function create_form_object($name, $data)
 {
    $inject=base64_encode(serialize($data));
    $valid=sha1(MY_SECRET . $inject);
    $payload="$inject/$valid";
    return "<input type='hidden' name='$name' value='$payload'>";
 } 

 function retrieve_form_object($name)
 {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$name])) {
        trigger_error("Specified object $name does not exist in request");
        return false;
    }
    list($data, $valid)=explode("/", $_REQUEST[$name]);
    $check=sha1(MY_SECRET . $data);
    if ($check===$valid) {
        return unserialize(base64_decode($data));
    } else {
        trigger_error("bad signature on $name");
        return false;
    }
 }
```

**update**

I had somewhat underestimated how easy a length extension attack is (thanks jh1711) hence I would suggest that a better solution is:

```
 define("MY_SECRET", sesion_id());

 function create_form_object($name, $data)
 {
    $inject=base64_encode(serialize($data));
    $valid=hash_hmac('sha1', $inject, MY_SECRET);
         // at a pinch, you could...
         // = sha1(MY_SECRET . sha1(MY_SECRET . $inject));
    $payload="$inject/$valid";
    return "<input type='hidden' name='$name' value='$payload'>";
 } 

 function retrieve_form_object($name)
 {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$name])) {
        trigger_error("Specified object $name does not exist in request");
        return false;
    }
    list($data, $valid)=explode("/", $_REQUEST[$name]);
    $check=hash_hmac('sha1', $data, MY_SECRET);
         // at a pinch, you could...
         // = sha1(MY_SECRET . sha1(MY_SECRET . $data));
    if ($check===$valid) {
        return unserialize(base64_decode($data));
    } else {
        trigger_error("bad signature on $name");
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Upvoted because you are absolutely right to warn. The OP probably wants to pass around relevant data via this trick, and is handling data from untrusted sources (I expect).

Comment: I agree with @ErwinMoller, but I have a small objection about the validation used. The way you use sha1 is vulnerable to a length extension attack ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) ). In this case this is not a problem because a serialized string can't be extended to anything dangerous (in almost all environments). But I would still prefer something like [hmac](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyed-Hash_Message_Authentication_Code).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at serialize:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

And use unserialize() to unpack.

Also, make sure the content (value in your html) is encoded. Eg, you don't want " in your content, because that terminates the string for value.

You can use htmlentities for that:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php